# Modifying an array in the state doesn't render to the page

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I want to have a simple array that upon clicking a button shuffles the array and then renders the new array instantly to the page.

The array gets shuffled once the page loads and the shuffle() function is successfully being called to completion when I click the `Shuffle` button, but the change never gets displayed to the user. I've tried setting the state explicitly and using this.setState() and neither one causes the array change to be rendered.

```
const Card = props => {
  return (
    <p>
      {props.title}: {props.text}
    </p>
  );
};

class Deck extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.shuffle = this.shuffle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      title: props.title,
      count: props.cards.length,
      cardsInDeck: props.cards
    };

    this.shuffle();
  }

  shuffle(e) {
    console.log("shuffling " + this.state.title + "...");

    let c = this.state.cardsInDeck.length;
    let shuffledArray = this.state.cardsInDeck;
    while (c > 0) {
      let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * c);
      c--;
      let temp = this.state.cardsInDeck[c];
      shuffledArray[c] = shuffledArray[index];
      shuffledArray[index] = temp;
    }

    //this.state.cardsInDeck = shuffledArray;
    this.setState({cardsInDeck: shuffledArray});

    console.log("done shuffling " + this.state.title + "...");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{this.state.title} - {this.state.count} cards</h5>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.shuffle}>
              Shuffle
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        {this.state.cardsInDeck}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

var jobs = [
  { title: "job1", text: "30", return: "20" },
  { title: "job2", text: "40", return: "30" },
  { title: "job3", text: "50", return: "40" },
  { title: "job4", text: "50", return: "40" },
  { title: "job5", text: "50", return: "40" },
  { title: "job6", text: "50", return: "40" },
  { title: "job7", text: "60", return: "50" }
];

const jobItems = jobs.map(job => (
  <Card key={job.title} title={job.title} text={job.text + " " + job.return} />
));

var workers = [
  { name: "worker1", cost: "30" },
  { name: "worker2", cost: "30" },
  { name: "worker3", cost: "30" },
  { name: "worker4", cost: "30" },
  { name: "worker5", cost: "30" },
  { name: "worker6", cost: "30" },
  { name: "worker7", cost: "30" }
];

const workerItems = workers.map(worker => (
  <Card key={worker.name} title={worker.name} text={worker.cost} />
));

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col">
          <Deck title="Jobs" cards={jobItems} />
        </div>
        <div className="col">
          <Deck title="Workers" cards={workerItems} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

## [Codepen - ChildStackTest](https://codepen.io/LuisCamachoIII/pen/OwmGQX?editors=0011)

How can I get this change displayed to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with the rendering of your components, but with the `shuffle()` method itself. The problem seems to lie here:

```
let shuffledArray = this.state.cardsInDeck;
```

This creates a variable which holds the **reference** to the state variable, and not a local copy for you to work on. The correct way of doing that would be:

```
let shuffledArray = this.state.cardsInDeck.slice();
```

Then also, change this line:

```
let temp = this.state.cardsInDeck[c];
```

to:

```
let temp = shuffledArray[c];
```

and it should work.

---

Working fork: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xJdNQO?editors=0011

Comment: This worked. Using slice() to make it a copy and not a reference is very creative. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. If you like ES6 you can also copy with `[...this.state.cardsInDeck]` if you prefer that syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You are mutating state directly on these rows:

```
let shuffledArray = this.state.cardsInDeck;

shuffledArray[c] = shuffledArray[index];
shuffledArray[index] = temp;
```

Might be the source of the problem ...

Comment: When I assigned `shuffledArray` to be `this.state.cardsInDeck`, is it getting assigned by reference? So any changes I make to `shuffledArray` get made to `this.state.cardsInDeck`? I thought javascript was always assigned by object?

Comment: Check out this article ... it mentions your issue and gives some nice solutions to it ... https://medium.freecodecamp.org/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5

Comment: +1 Ah, so it **was** assigning by reference after all, so any changes to [shuffledArray] were modifying the state as well, which should be treated immutable. That is definitely the source of my problem. Thanks!